# Extract a sub-string that is in between two certain words using regex in LabVIEW

Tags: regex, labview

For an example, Given a string Voltage123Current, I want to extract 123 using regex. I did try positive look-ahead and look-behind but that did not work.
(?<=Voltage)\d+(?=Current)

I'd appreciate your help on this.

Best,
Jatin

Answer (score 2):

use `Voltage(\d+)` if you want to match  `Voltage123Current` or `Voltage123anySymbolOrAlpa`

update: `Voltage(\d+)Current` to match only `Voltage123Current`

```js
var str = 'Voltage123Current';
digit = str.match(/Voltage(\d+)Current/);
console.log(digit[1])
```

Comment: Does not answer the question, only looks at digits after the pre-string

Comment: its shortcut, sometimes its not necessary to define post-string.  but I updated the answer as you like. :D

Answer (score 2):

```
(WordBefore)(.*)(WordAfter)
```

This will capture a match consisting of the WordBefore (submatch1), followed by a multitude of character (submatch2), and WordAfter (submatch3):[image: GetStringBetween]

It's a neat little trick to use submatches, just extent the Regex block to get them

Comment: this also does not 100% answer the question, it has negative result `Voltage123-+$Current` => `123-+$`, `Voltage123dummyCurrent` => `123dummy`

Answer (score 0):

Tried (?=Voltage)*[0-9]*(?=Current) as reg exp and it gave me the integer values between Voltage and Current

This is the output from [regexr.com](http://regexr.com):

[image]